# json php сравнение и вывод данных

Tags: php, json

прошу помощи, считываю json через php и получаю время в таком виде

00:01 03:00 06:05 06:20 08:00 23:10

```
foreach ($obj->schedule as $statement)
{
    $dep = $statement->departure;
    echo "<div>".$dep."</div>";
}
```

как сравнить с текущим временем и вывести только записи с разницей в + - 10 минут

Большое спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

```php
date_default_timezone_set ($timezone)); //установи нужную зону
if (abs(strtotime($dep)-time()) <= 600) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Для strtotime можно указать правильный часовой пояс. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Ну, или чуть короче (c учетом ранее выполненного `date_default_timezone_set ($timezone)`): `if (abs(strtotime($dep)-time()) <= 600) { do somesing }`. :)

Comment: а как быть когда время переходит 00:00

Comment: Если установлена правильная тайм зона, то должно быть все нормально

Comment: Спасибо всем, да с установкой правильной тайм зоны все отлично работает